# Is there a package for turning a beamer presentation into a grey scale presentation?

Tags: beamer, packages, color

I have a beamer presentation in latex where I want to turn the colors into grayscale colors. It includes some graphics and text in various colors, and I want to eliminate this. Is there a way to just include a package and turn a given document/presentation to be black and white?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the option `gray` to the package `xcolor`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
```

**EDIT:**

blackandwhite wrote that it doesn't have any effect. Here is a full minimal working example which works well:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}
\section{Abschnitt Nr.2}
\subsection{Listen I}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Aufz\"ahlung}
\begin{itemize}
\item Einf\"uhrungskurs in \LaTeX
\item Kurs 2
\item Seminararbeiten und Pr\"asentationen mit \LaTeX
\item Die Beamerclass
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Aufz\"ahlung mit Pausen}
\begin{itemize}
\item Einf\"uhrungskurs in \LaTeX \pause
\item Kurs 2 \pause
\item Seminararbeiten und Pr\"asentationen mit \LaTeX \pause
\item Die Beamerclass
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. it has no effect on the presentation.

Comment: @blackandwhite: I edited my post.

Comment: @blackandwhite Do you mean you have external graphic files (.png, .jpg, etc) in colour, and they're not coming out as grayscale? AFAIK the only way to get them in B&W is to edit them in an external image editing program.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking to change the color of text, header, footer and background, several of the default themes are b/w and grayscale.

```
\usecolortheme{beetle}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\usecolortheme{fly}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\usecolortheme{structure}
```

These will result in remarkably different amounts of black vs. white with different themes. For example, try any (one) of the above with any (one) of the following.

```
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usetheme{Singapore}
```

But these would not convert your graphics files to b/w. This would only affect the parts of the layout that beamer colors in for you.

Here is a nice beamer theme gallery.
http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/